Use UDF for RDD in pyspark
I want to use the user-defined function (UDF) below for RDD in Pyspark
from pyspark.sql.functions import abs as pyspark_abs, sum as pyspark_sum, \
                    rand as pyspark_rand, min as pyspark_min, max as pyspark_max, \
                    radians as pyspark_radians, cos as pyspark_cos, sin as pyspark_sin, \
                    sqrt as pyspark_sqrt, atan2 as pyspark_atan2

def distance(point1, point2):
    lat1, lon1 = point1
    lat2, lon2 = point2
    R = 6371  # Radius of the Earth in kilometers
    dlat = pyspark_radians(lat2 - lat1)
    dlon = pyspark_radians(lon2 - lon1)
    a = pyspark_sin(dlat / 2) * pyspark_sin(dlat / 2) + pyspark_cos(pyspark_radians(lat1)) * pyspark_cos(pyspark_radians(lat2)) * pyspark_sin(dlon / 2) * pyspark_sin(dlon / 2)
    c = 2 * pyspark_atan2(pyspark_sqrt(a), pyspark_sqrt(1 - a))
    distance = R * c
    return distance

spark.udf.register("distance", distance)

However, when I apply it for RDD like below
neighbors = radian_rdd.cartesian(radian_rdd) \
                   .filter(lambda x: x[0][1] < x[1][1]) \
                   .filter(lambda x: distance(x[0][0], x[1][0]) <= eps) \
                   .map(lambda x: (x[0][1], x[1][1]))

I get this error
PySparkTypeError(pyspark.errors.exceptions.base.PySparkTypeError: [NOT_COLUMN_OR_STR] Argument `col` should be a Column or str, got float.)

I have tried to debug but it doesn't work. I want to make it work well.

cos as pyspark_cos operates only on a column not on individual values. In distance function, you have to use math.sin math.cos instead of pyspark's sin or cos.
